# Finding values of $\text{Log}$ of $i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

> Find all values of $\log(\sqrt 3 -i)$.

> Solution:
>
> $\log z = \log(√3 - i) = \ln(r + iθ) = \ln|z| + iθ$
>
> It is clear that $\ln|z| = \ln\sqrt{3 + 1} = \ln|2|$
>
> Hence $θ = \ln(√3/2) - \pi/2$.

I do not understand the last line how the principal angle is derived; I assume the principal angle would be $\tan^{-1} (1/3)$, which would make $\arg(z)=\tan^{-1} (1/3)+2n\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given working is dead wrong. $\sqrt3-i=2e^{-i\pi/6}$, so $\log(\sqrt3-i)=\log2+(-\pi/6+2k\pi)i$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: thank you, so is $-\pi$/6 obtained by my tan formula?

Comment: @jamesblack Yes.

Comment: sorry not sure if my calculator is wrong, but $-\pi/6$ does not equal to $tan^{-1}$(1/3)?

Comment: @jamesblack Did you even read the problem correctly? It is not $3-i$ but $\sqrt3-i$.

Comment: yea i realized my above tan formula is wrong sorry--one last question, using sin/cos/tan is the only way to obtain the principal angle correct?

Comment: @jamesblack Well, it is the most straightforward way to obtain the angle.